# Creating the start of a Caesar cipher

Tags: c#, beginner, caesar-cipher

My code takes an input, uses the input to take a number of letters from the start of the alphabet and put them at the end. I intend to use this to create a Caesar style cipher.

Is there a way to do this more elegantly?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            GettingInput gi = new GettingInput();
            var input = gi.GetInput();
            Console.WriteLine("Your input:\n{0}", input);
            List<char> alphabet = new List<char>();


            for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
            {
                alphabet.Add(c);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
            {
                alphabet.Add(alphabet[i]);
            }

            for (int i = input ; i > 0; i--)
            {
                alphabet.Remove(alphabet[i-1]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(alphabet[i]);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class GettingInput
    {
        public int GetInput()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please input an int:");
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    return input;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    Console.WriteLine("Please input a valid int:");
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

All feedback welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Instead of create the whole list and modify it subsequently, you could calculate the value directly.

The code could like that:

```
static void Main()
{
    GettingInput gi = new GettingInput();
    var input = gi.GetInput();
    Console.WriteLine("Your input:\n{0}", input);

    var first = (int)'a';
    var last = (int)'z';
    var length = last - first;

    var query = Enumerable
        .Range(0, length)
        .Select(i => (char)(first + ((input + i) % length)));

    foreach (var number in query)
        Console.WriteLine(number);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

- You could use `int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input)` instead of catching the exception

Comment: Good idea, but I prefer to avoid mutation in LINQ statements and to minimize mutation in general, so there is a smaller opportunity for bugs.  You can write it without mutation like this: `Enumerable.Range(0, length).Select(i => (char)(first + ((input + i) % length)))`

Comment: @RiskyMartin: Good point, thanks. I modified the answer as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I should make your life easier with Linq and also introduce you to advanced way for implementing your program.

1. This line of code

   ```
        List<char> alphabet = new List<char>();    
           for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
           {
               alphabet.Add(c);
           }
   ```

   can be written as

   `List<char> alphabet= Enumerable.Range('a', 'z' - 'a' + 1).Select(value=> (Char)value).ToList();`

First, It creates a range of a-z which are represented in numbers, converts it to character using the explicit cast and converts it to a list .

1. This line of code

   ```
      for(int i = 0; i < input; i++)
           {
               alphabet.Add(alphabet[i]);
           }
   ```

   could be written as 
   `alphabet.AddRange(alphabet.GetRange(0, input));`
2. This Line of code

   ```
   for (int i = input ; i > 0; i--)
           {
               alphabet.Remove(alphabet[i-1]);
           }
   ```

   could be written as
   `alphabet.RemoveRange(0,input);`
3. Please don't do this

   'while (true)
           {.....
            }`
   It is regarded as a bad programming practice [While true a bad programming practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142144/whiletrue-and-loop-breaking-anti-pattern)
4. Rather than using try and catch use (this was from [Parsing an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366684/c-sharp-failed-parse-exception)

   `int i;
   if(!int.TryParse(i,out value))
   {
       // You caught it without throwing an exception.
   }`
5. Note rather than catching all exceptions - ArgumentNullException,FormatException,OverflowException are the exceptions that could occur in your scenario.